# Battleship, size matter?

Tags: probability

here is the dilemma I'm facing, I'm designing a game, it's a Battleship with a tweak, you can choose your ships and build a fleet.

Now, I need to assign a value, or resource consumption to every ship, since size now only a characteristic of the ship.

Ships will also have special abilities, like for example, some ships will be able to clear tiles every now and then, not shoot, but reveal what is there.

OK, back to business, here is my dilemma, I don't know if having a ship with more tiles, like a carrier (5 x 1) is better than having a ship with 1 or 2 tiles. Better in terms of how much time will it take to sink that ship.

After a while, I concluded that this question is probably a purely mathematical one, I could be wrong, but I think it is, it involves probability and some for of combinations.

If you know how can I determine what is the better ship, I'd appreciate it.

(Don't take into account any other ship property, those examples were given only to provide some context).

Thanks!.

Comment: The ship that gets found gets sunk fairly quickly...  Thus suggesting that a smaller number of tiles creates a smaller chance of the initial 'find' and thus a smaller ultimate chance of being destroyed.

Comment: Sure, but at the same time, all those shots you need to make to sink the ship, are shots made by the opponent trying to find your other, smaller, ship. If possible, I'd like to calculate with precision what is better.

Comment: Start with the probability of finding $n$ ships of $m$ size each; then calculate the number of turns required to sink those ships.  I believe that a (near-constant) value of $m\cdot n$ will yield a maximum expected turn count at $m=1$.

Comment: Put another way:  suppose ship $X$ has been found, and it has $m$ tiles.  How many turns are required to absolutely guarantee it has been destroyed?  I think $m+2$ or $m+3$ would be the expected value.  Now if each "ship" is not required to be linear then the game changes...